# How do array's in java work and what is a data type of the class mean?

Tags: java, arrays, object, types

Please can you explain to me if we want to add an element to a the end of a preexisting array how is it properly done.

I am having difficulty understanding the Littler class specifically the add method.

I understand that "Puppy[] temp = new Puppy[this.puppies.length + 1];"

We have a new array that is one greater in length than the puppies array (instance variable).  "temp[i] = this.puppies[i];" assigns all the elements from the puppies array to the temp based on the indexes.

My confusion lies with line: temp[this.puppies.length] = puppy;

1.) What exactly is happening here?

In my mind I think that we are reassigning the last index position of this.puppies.length to the puppy parameter.

2.) Will that +1 (one size bigger) that was made, the extra index of the temp array on the line

"Puppy[] temp = new Puppy[this.puppies.length + 1];"

remain blank?

3.) Does "this.puppies = temp;"  represent a shallow copy?

4.) What is this process called of making a bigger array and adding an object, do we have to do it every time (create an array one bigger).

5.) What happens if we don't, is there a situation where we don't have to make one bigger, or need a temp array? (I am just confused as to why we need it).

6.) What does an object of the class type mean? What does "private Puppy[] puppies;" mean exactly?

7.) Please can you help me decipher this code so I can understand. Especially with a hypothetical example if this.values.length was an array of a size of 5 elements (index 0-4).

```
//Class where add actions taking place
public class Litter {
    private Puppy[] puppies;

    public Litter() {
        this.puppies = new Puppy[0];
    }
    public void add(Puppy puppy) {
        Puppy[] temp = new Puppy[this.puppies.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < puppies.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = this.puppies[i];
        }
        temp[this.puppies.length] = puppy;
        this.puppies = temp; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Following on from @user7's answer for questions (4) and (5), adding an extra element to array beyond it's original size would require creating a new array (and then iterating through copying the values from the old to the new).  This is a real pain - and is a major reason why we typically use classes like `ArrayList` where we can simply add new elements to the end without any hassle.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost - arrays indices are 0 based. If you have an array of size 10, the valid array indices are from 0 to 9.

> temp[this.puppies.length] = puppy

This stores the *reference* to some `Puppy` object (`puppy`) as the **last** element of the array. (since the length of `temp` is `puppies.length + 1`)

> Will that +1 (one size bigger) that was made, the extra index of the temp array on the line [..] remain blank

No. The above assignment was made to the last element as arrays use 0-based indexing.

> Does "this.puppies = temp;" represent a shallow copy?

No new object is created. After the assignment, both variables, `this.puppies` and the Puppy array (`temp`), point to the same object on the heap.

> What is this process called of making a bigger array and adding an object, do we have to do it every time (create an array one bigger).

There is no general name for this. It is done here to add a new element to the array. Generally, to avoid this (often), a new array of double the size would be created.

> What happens if we don't, is there a situation where we don't have to make one bigger, or need a temp array? (I am just confused as to why we need it).

Since arrays cannot be resized, you have to create a bigger array if you want to add a new object.

> What does an object of the class type mean? What does "private Puppy[] puppies;" mean exactly?
>   `puppies` is an object that holds an *array* of `Puppy` objects.
>
> Please can you help me decipher this code so I can understand. Especially with a hypothetical example if this.values.length was an array of a size of 5 elements (index 0-4).

This method is to add a new Puppy to the existing ones. Since arrays cannot be resized dynamically, it creates a new array(`temp`) and adds all the existing puppies. To accommodate a new Puppy, the created array size is one greater than the existing puppies. Then, it adds the passed Puppy instance as the last element of the array. The last line `this.puppies = temp` assigns the reference of the created array to the instance variable that points the puppies array.